# ¿Como implementar Ajax para la conexión de 2 archivos JSP?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, mysql-workbench

Tengo un formulario en un archivo Jsp llamada Prueba.jsp que hace referencia a otro de nombre Modificar.jsp en donde tengo mis operaciones para realizar el alta,baja y modificaciones de registros en base a una consulta mysql.

**Prueba.jsp**

```html
   <form action="" method="post" name="Actualizar2">
<td>Id</td>
<input type="text" name="idPersona2" value="" size="40"/>

<td>Nombre</td>
<input type="text" name="NombreCompleto2" value="" size="40"/>

<td>Edad</td>
<input type="text" name="Edad2" value="" size="40"/>

<td>Pais</td>
<input type="text" name="Pais2" value="" size="40"/>

<br><br><br><input type="radio" name="Action" value="Actualizar"/>Actualizar
<input type="radio" name="Action" value="Eliminar"/>Eliminar
<input type="radio" name="Action" value ="Crear"/>Crear

<div2 id="prueba">
     <br><br><br><input type="submit" id="recibir" value="Aceptar" name="Aceptar"/><br><br><br>
</div2>
```

Y quiero mostrar el resultado de la operación en Prueba.jsp

**Modificar.jsp**

```
<form action="Prueba.jsp" method="post" name="Actualizar">
La siguiente instrucción fue ejecutada:
<br/><br/>
<%=ls_query%>
<br/><br/>

El resultado fue:
<br/><br/>
<%=ls_result%>
<br/><br/>



<br><br><input type="submit" value="Volver" />
</form>
```

Trato de hacerlo mediante una instrucción Ajax que programe en Prueba.jsp, la cual declare de la siguiente manera:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("recibir").value;
var prueba = document.getElementById("prueba").value;

var recibir = new XMLHttpRequest();

recibir.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(recibir.readyState === 4) {
    if(recibir.status === 200) { 
      prueba.innerHTML = recibir.responseText;
    } else {
      prueba.innerHTML = "An error occurred during your request: " +  recibir.status + " " + recibir.statusText;
    } 
  }
};

recibir.open("Get", "Modificar.jsp");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
  recibir.send();
});
```

Pero no ejecuta la instrucción, espero sus comentarios.

Comment: Que error te esta mostrando

Comment: No me aparece como tal un error en pantalla, solo me recarga el formulario pero no modifica ningún dato en mi tabla de SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Estás simplemente añadiendo un listener al botón `recibir`, pero el evento que debes interceptar es el `submit` del formulario.

Primero, agrega un `id` al formulario:

```
<form id="actualizar2">
```

Luego, selecciónalo del DOM:

```
const form = document.getElementById('actualizar2');
```

Y por último suscribe un *listener* un evento `submit` del formulario:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function onSubmit (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // previene el comportamiento submit por defecto
  // aquí ya puedes hacer tu petición ajax
});
```

Es importante prevenir el comportamiento por defecto del evento `submit` para poder ejecutar la lógica ajax, ya que, de otra manera, se enviará una petición `HTTP` normal.